# "<<" operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am very new to d3 and have somewhat limited knowledge in Javascript. I am studying this example from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797 and stuck with the code.

in the example you will find a `zoom` function as described below:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
.scale(1 << 12)
.scaleExtent([1 << 9, 1 << 23])
.translate([width / 2, height / 2])
.on("zoom", zoomed);
```

I do not know what is `<<` in Javascript, from D3 wiki and tutorials I understand the `scaleExtent()` takes a two element array with max and min values, but can someone please explain how this values are being calculated and the logic behind this.

Comment: [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: It is a Bitwise operator. You can read about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<<` is one of the [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). More specifically, it's the [left shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3C%3C_%28Left_shift%29). What it does is

> Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the left, shifting in zeros from the right.

Here it looks like it's just used to simply express powers of two : `1 << 12` is `2^12`